# Could not login to admin site anymore after moving from Mnesia to MySQL in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

I got stuck in using ejabberd and JSXC after installing with default configuration and move from Mnesia to MySQL, I could not login to admin site anymore. I checked log as below :

```
2015-08-06 15:50:32.972 [error] <0.3196.0>@ejabberd_auth:is_user_exists:313 The authentication module ejabberd_auth_odbc returned an error
when checking user <<"ejabberd">> in server <<"10.30.173.89">>
Error message: <<"Unknown Host">>
```

By the way, could you please help me to create MUC (multi-user chat), I don't know how to config it in JSXC and ejabberd.

Comment: You should not ask two different questions into the same SO question. This will be confusing reader. You should also give more information on version of ejabberd and show what you changed in configuration file.

Comment: For the part on creating MUC, here is an example SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876352/error-creating-chat-room-strophejs-with-ejabberd = You just need to send presence to MUC room to create it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in your configuration. "Unknown Host" error for the SQL query means that ejabberd could not find any MySQL database configured for that domain.

You need to check and fix your ejabberd configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I also have same question in same scenario.

I can add a new user from command line and also view it in my MySQL DB

```
./ejabberdctl register test2 localhost test2
```

But getting unknown host error when the user is trying to connect from client.